# specialties field was removed from the LinkedIn API?

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm trying to get the "specialties" field from the LinkedIn API but it returns nothing. So, this field is still avalible?

note: I barely use LinkedIn and I'm using my account to develop this app, so, maybe that field is empty. If it's that case, please tell where I can find it.

[Basic Profile Fields](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/fields/basic-profile)

Answer (score 2):

The **specialties** field has been removed from the API as stated [here](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/4977/linkedin-skills-overview?lang=en), but the [API docs](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/fields/basic-profile) haven't been updated.

In my case, I can see the previous content of that field added to the **summary** field as plain text: "*my-cv-summary \nSpecialties: my-specialties*".

btw, you can test the API here https://apigee.com/console/linkedin using this URL:

https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(summary,specialties)?format=json

...and allowing **apigee**  to connect to your profile, obviously. You'll see that no specialties field is returned, but if you had informed that field before the change, you'll see it's content added to the summary.