# LinkedIn API - What is the "Specialties" field?

Tags: linkedin-api

In the LinkedIn API for "Sign in with LinkedIn", access is provided to several basic profile fields of a user, including "specialties." Does anyone have a sense of what this field refers to? LinkedIn got rid of "specialties" as an entry in their profile, so I'm wondering what data the API would be pulling for the "specialties" field?

https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/fields/basic-profile

Answer (score 0):

The specialties field has been removed from the API, but the change hasn't been documented. Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37127405/specialties-field-was-removed-from-the-linkedin-api/39507218).